# Is there a way to enumerate the child states of the current state in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a couple use cases for angularjs ui-router.  I may want to enumerate over the child states of the current state and generate links for those states.   I may also want to go to a single child state when the current state `isValid` or `isCompleted` thus effecting wizard like functionality.

I have not been able to find a way to enumerate the child states of the current state.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Going through [the docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router), it looks like you'd have to call `$state.get()` to get *all* the states, then filter for ones that are children of the current state. It's probably best to put this operation in a `resolve` function so that it will be completed before instantiating the controller for your view.